# $timeout runs instantly instead of waiting for the timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, settimeout

I'm working on a service that shows a notification and hides it after some specific time, but the code in $timeout runs instantly, I know that the showing part works because when I run it line by line I can see it, but as soon as I go to the timeout line it is hidden, the time out in this section is set for 10 seconds. below is the $timeout part

```
    $timeout(() => {
        var domElement = angular.element(
            document.querySelector('#toast-notification')
        );
        domElement.removeClass('show');
    }, data.eventDuration);
```

Comment: What do you get on `data.eventDuration`?

Comment: Note that `data.eventDuration` has to be `10000` for 10 seconds

Comment: Is the duration set to `10` or `10000`? The timeout value is interpreted as a number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `data.eventDuration` has to be `10000` for 10 seconds, because `$timeout` is working with milliseconds.

```
var data = {};
data.eventDuration = 10000;
// now your function should be called after 10 seconds.

$timeout(() => {
    var domElement = angular.element(
        document.querySelector('#toast-notification')
    );
    domElement.removeClass('show');
}, data.eventDuration);
```